# HighCharts for stock prediction data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using `HighChart` library for creating charts in my web application in `ASP .Net`.
First i use this [Candlestick](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick) chart for showing the company's stock on chart.

Now i want to create chart for forecast data (`RSI` `CFM` `Typical Price` `Moving Average`) values on chart.
I see the following picture somewhere but i don't have its example or demo.
Is there any working example for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like scenario where indicator are calculated as additonal series. Check the plugins registry, where some of them are implemented.

http://highcharts.com/plugin-registry

Comment: Thanks i will check that :)